# Mitmproxy allow remote connections/disable block_global

Tags: python, ubuntu, mitmproxy

I have mitmproxy running on a ubuntu 18.04 vps however whenever I try and connect from my pc I get warning client connection from (ip) killed by block_global. How can I stop block_global killing the connection? I am starting the proxy with `mitmproxy -p 3128` and have not made any changes too the base files.

Answer (score 3):

Just start `mitmproxy` setting the concerned option to false:

```
mitmproxy -p 3128 --set block_global=false
```

**Important**: make sure that your mitmproxy is not reachable from the Internet, because in that case it will be probably detected sooner than later by an open proxy scanner, and might start to be used by random users as a proxy.